# How to send correct headers for Excel file in a Zend Framework Response

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am having issue with setting headers for xls file while downloading through Zend Framework.

I have tried this but not working...

```
$this->getResponse()
         ->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/vnd.ms-excel')
         ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=test.xls');
```

Still it shows some binary data. and not setting headers.

Please help me though this.

Comment: How are you outputting the data to the browser? If you're using `exit()` or any other method to interrupt the dispatch loop the proper headers may not be sent.

Comment: Did you try using native php header function, as show, e.g. at http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/05/25/download-files-with-zend-framework/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', true)
```

Use true in the third argument to force replacement of the header

and add

```
->setHeader('Content-Length', ...)
```